Unwanted window expansion
Since a recent update to Sequoia, every time Safari is opened (and sometimes when changing to another tab), it opens at full screen.  Mail does the same, and I think others.  Before the update, they would open to the same geometry they had in the previous use.
How can this unwanted expansion be turned off?

If you make a new user account, it doesn’t happen there, does it?

Haven't tried that, but I will.  I didn't change any settings—it started with an O.S. update.
